# Is it possible to find local app data from uwp application on raspberry on SD card?

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi, local-storage, appdata

Is it possible to find these data somewhere on the sdcard if i pull it out and insert it in pc through SD card reader? If it is possible where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the files that the developers themselves saved somewhere (maybe locally), then yes. But it's up to them where it is.

If you mean local or roaming data, like files or settings, that is provided by UWP API, then no. It's saved somewhere in the system's directory made for this app (and users).

[More about it is in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data)

These are the main types of app data:

- Local: stored on the device, backed up in the cloud, and persists
  across updates
- LocalCache: persistent data that exists on the current device, not
  backed up, and persists across updates
- SharedLocal: persistent across all app users
- Roaming: exists on all devices where the user has installed the app
- Temporary: can be deleted by the system at any time

If you're looking for the app's folder (provided for every UWP app) then it's here:

%LocalAppData%\Packages\

Though it's messy. There are files in there in every folder that represent above folder structure. I don't think they're encrypted, and you could read these files (e.g. through the API itself) though I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry if this is stupid question but is it ciphered in some way? Or how is it you can not read it even if you knew exactly where to look.

Comment: "If you mean the files that the developers themselves saved somewhere (maybe locally), then yes. But it's up to them where it is." I thought this is not possible - can UWP create or read file anywhere on disk?

Comment: If you allow it and explicitly call File Dialog then yes. You can give it access to any folder in the system you want (if current user also has access to).